# Enterprise SharePoint 2013: Changing Font Size and Color for Text Body everywhere

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have around 100 odd pages in my application help files in SharePoint, and users are complaining that the font size and color is not suitable for their reading.

Apart from using CSS in every single page, how do I change the settings of my site, so that any paragraph text used is changed to the new settings?

I just need to update the font color to a darker shade of black and increase the size by 2 - 4 px.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the link to your css in the Site Master Page.
either inside oslo.master or seattle.master based on which template you used with your site.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/YourStyleSheet.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled publishing feature, you may set master page Alternate CSS url(site settings->master page).

[image]

```
//your css
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain{    
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}
```